# Use perf report taking symbols from a specific binary file

Tags: linux, perf

I'm collecting data with

```
perf record -o "filename.here" -a --call-graph dwarf -p `pidof binary.here`
```

And reading it with

```
perf report -i "filename.here"
```

However this stops working when my live binary gets changed/rebuilt (due to me constantly updating it since it's a work in progress) saying "binary with build id XXX cannot be found". I am saving the old binary for which I collected data but it seems there's no way for `perf report` to explicitly load a specific binary (there's the `--symfs` option but that's to look for ALL debug symbols there for all libraries/etc which is also not a solution).

One other solution would be to stop the live binary and copy paste the backed up binary instead of it, but I can't afford to stop the live binary just to do this. Another solution would be to copy the backed up binary on a different server so I can store it in the same path perf is trying to search for it.

Is there any actual better solution for this?

Comment: Why would you have to stop the live binary?  You could temporarily rename it, and symlink or hardlink the binary that matches your profile data to that name.  (Ugly, but works fine unless the running process tries to re-exec itself right then.)  You can even unlink a binary while processes are running from it, but then you won't be able to link it back into the filesystem.)  There's hopefully a better solution with perf command line options, but I haven't looked.

Comment: I remember doing that long time ago and it instantly crashed (worth mentioning I run it under gdb all the time, maybe related?). However I did that now and seeks to be ok, thanks. Still, a perf command line would be better

Answer (score 4):

That message:

```
binary with build id XXX cannot be found
```

Is there because `perf record` will, at the end of the recording phase, save a copy of the binaries with samples, so that if you later update it, no problem, that specific binary was saved under `~/.debug/.build/id/AA/BBCCDDEEFF001122` and that is what `perf report` and other consumers will lookup.

Then this is a matter of figuring out why that build id is not being found. Are you using both 'perf record' and 'perf report' in the same machine?

Also what:

```
perf buildid-list -i filename.here
```

Says?

Look at your ~/.debug/ directory for that file.

```
perf buildid-list -i /path/to/binary
```

will tell you the buildid for a binary.